# Structure of B+ trees

Tags: b-tree

According to the properties of B+ trees,every node except the root has to be atleast half filled.
But suppose we have a B+ tree with a node capable of holding maximum of **3 KEYS**.Then how much minimum number of entries(not pointers) should be there in a node of a B+ tree.Is it 2 or 1?.
According to http://www.cburch.com/cs/340/reading/btree/index.html in the first figure it has only 1 entry(16) in the right child of the root.

.

Comment: It is good to see people taking the algorithm's invariant seriously (+1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then how much minimum number of entries(not pointers) should be there in a node of a B+ tree.Is it 2 or 1?.

1 ("Every non-leaf, non-root node has at least floor(d / 2) children.") => 2 children  => 1 key

This is not in fact the real picture. B+ trees are design to work on
disk (to be stored in a file), so each tree node will use a disk block or
multiple of disk block size. In normal cases  B+ trees have nodes of for
example 100 keys. (but it is much easier to explain the algorithms with small size trees).

Thank you for the excelente B+ Tree reference.

Comment: But then how does it ensures that a node is atleast half filled

Comment: Normally I  state that "half filled" applies to the "pointers". In fact I fill more comfortable with odd k.  With very big k the problem "disappears". There is a number of variants of B+ trees that uses slightly different invariant .